# How to make a discord bot send post request with a cron job

Tags: python-3.x, post, cron, discord.py

I recently decided to get a status page for my website https://status.microwavebot.tech (Betteruptime is used) but I also wanted to show my bot on there and the only way I can do is a heartbeat which requires a cron job to send a post request.

I really hope one of you can help me because I can't find anything on this subject

Comment: Parse the interval using [croniter](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter) then pass it into [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) and it'll loop in background for the specified time from which you may make post requests to your desired end-point.

Comment: I am a fairly new developer and unsure how to do this, could you give me an idea on how to? Thanks